# How to make Radio buttons of the same Radio group align in several columns in Material UI?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I’m new in the React.js field. So I'm a bit worried about my question on Stackoverflow. I would like everyone to forgive me for my immature question. I tried to find the right answer for my issue, but I couldn’t find it.
Now I’m using Fuse React Theme for my one project, I need to align radio buttons of one Radio group in several columns.
I have tried in several ways, but those are not the proper ways to handle this, I know. So I don’t write my tries. Here is what I have to do

```
<RadioGroupFormsy
     className="my-8"
     name="question"
     variant="outlined"
     color="primary"
     value="A"
     required
>
    <FormControlLabel value="A" control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label="A"/>
    <FormControlLabel value="B" control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label="B"/>
    <FormControlLabel value="C" control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label="C"/>
    <FormControlLabel value="D" control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label="D"/>
    <FormControlLabel value="E" control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label="E"/>
    <FormControlLabel value="F" control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label="F"/>
    <FormControlLabel value="G" control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label="G"/>
    <FormControlLabel value="H" control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label="H"/>
    <FormControlLabel value="I" control={<Radio color="primary"/>} label="I"/>
</RadioGroupFormsy>
```

I would like to align those like this.

```
A   D   G
B   E   H
C   F   I
```

Please help me.

Comment: hello, @Devbluesky. Did you check my url?

Comment: Yes,@Glistern, I have already tried to use the grid system of the Tailwind css. But it didn't work.

Comment: So you fix the your problem?

Comment: My answer is correct?

Comment: OK, Please give me your more detail, give me exactly code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout)

**styles.css**

```
form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-7tlo0)

Comment: Hi, @lissettdm, thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work properly as I wanted. Anyways, it helps a lot. Thanks

Comment: Hi, @devbluesky111 your welcome, I think that you don't need to use an extra lib to solve your problem, but maybe I don't know about the context of your problem :)

Comment: Yes, well, the Fuse React theme uses Tailwind CSS, so I could solve my issue properly with the help of the former replier. Thanks again